# Using <script> tag to access data passed in from GET request

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mean-stack

I think I may be misunderstanding how to use <%- variable %> items in javascript.

Right now, I have a database of "recipes". Each recipe has a name and some ingredients, and I am using a GET request on :_id to build a separate page for each recipe. This part is working okay.

Where I am struggling is in building a method to iterate over the ingredients and append them to the DOM. Here's where I'm at right now:

```
<script>

    for (var i = 0; i < <%- ingredients.length %>; i++) {
        console.log(i); <-- Works normally
        console.log('<%- ingredients[0].ingredient %>'); <---displays normally
        console.log('<%- ingredients[i].ingredient %>'); <--throws error(does not recognize i)
    }

</script>
```

Is it not possible to iterate over the ingredients? Is there a different approach I should be considering?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Here is the GET request:

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    Recipe.findOne({_id : req.params.id }, function(error, document) {
        if (error || !document) {
            res.render('error', {});            
        }
        else {
            // res.render('recipe', {document : document});
            // res.json(document);
            // document = JSON.parse(document);
            console.log(document.name);
            console.log(document.ingredients)
            res.render('recipe.html', { 
                ingredients : document.ingredients,
                name : document.name,
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ChefHeather</title>
    <link href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link href="/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div id="header1" class="container col-sm-12 createContainer">
        <h1><%= name %></h1>
        <p><%- ingredients[0].ingredient %> <%- ingredients[0].quantity %></p>
    </div>


    <script>

        for (var i = 0; i < <%- ingredients.length %>; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            console.log('<%- ingredients[0].ingredient %>');
            console.log('<%- ingredients[1].ingredient %>');
        }

    </script>

    <script>


    </script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/ng-resource//dist/ng-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="../js/mainCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Once I figure out how to do this, I will just use javascript to append each element of an ingredient to the DOM

Comment: Can you tell me what does ingredients implies. Is it a response?

Comment: Can you share the html.

Comment: @Jayaraj.K I will update the post

Comment: I guess you need to itereate values you are getting inside the <p> tag using. Is that what you need ?

Comment: @Jayaraj.K Yeah...I'm just not sure how to do that. I was going to remove the <p> tag and use the <script> to build <p> tags and append them, but I can't seem to figure out how to iterate with the <%- ingredients[i].ingredient %> It says that "i" is an unknown variable there.